# In C++ how can I input a string into a char array of struct?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner student in computer science and I faced a problem which I couldn't find the solution for it anywhere. 
When I tried to input a string using `cin.get();`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int SIZE = 0;

struct Books {
    float isbn;
    string author;
    string Bname;
};

void funAddb(Books book[], int);

int main()
{

    int choose;
    Books book[SIZE];
    int n;
    do {
        cout << " WELCOME \n ENTER (2) to return a borrowed book:";
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case 2:
            funAddb(book, SIZE);
            break;
        }
        cout << endl
             << "If you want to stop please enter (0):" << endl;
        cin >> n;
    } while (n != 0);
    return 0;
}

void funAddb(Books b[], int SIZE)
{
    cout << endl
         << "Please enter the book name:" << endl;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    getline(cin, b[SIZE].Bname);
    cout << endl
         << "Please enter the ISBN:" << endl;
    cin >> b[SIZE].isbn;
    cout << endl
         << "Please enter the author name:" << endl;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    getline(cin, b[SIZE].author);
    SIZE++;
}
```

The size should be changeable not fixed, the solution that i found suggested that i change the size of the array to 100 but i don't know whats the purpose of that

Comment: By using `b[SIZE]` you are introducing bug known a buffer overflow. `SIZE` is outside of valid index range. Also you are using `cin.ignore` in incorrect way what most probably leads to problems you are observing.

Comment: For this you can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which is a variable size container that will be resized as you add objects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by saying that next time you should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since it's not clear what your problem is, and where you got your "solution" from.
It is told you to put a fixed size in order to **allow a lot of elements to be put in your array**, but this is a bad approach for two big reasons:

- The size is not changeable as you said. So if you reach 100 books, you cannot add anymore
- It is a big waste of memory in your PC in case you do not fill in your array completely

In order to change the size of a c++ array you can use pointers to initialize a "dynamic" array, with the syntax `Books *mybooks = new Books[SIZE]`, although it is still not the best option to use because pointers are saved in the **heap** of your computer's RAM, which basically means that you have to handle the size and the memory yourself, the computer doesn't do it for you just like for static arrays.

As you proceed with your programming career, you will find out that people have created faster algorithms, containers and other things. The standard template's [vector class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) comes in very handy in your case and its syntax is very easy:

```cpp
int SIZE=0;
struct Books{
 float isbn;
 string author;
 string Bname;
};
vector<Books> mybooks; //create empty vector
vector<Books> mybooks2(SIZE); //create vector with dimension

Books newBook; //initialize new book
mybooks.push_back(newBook) //add your book to the container
```

I also recommend to use classes instead of structs; although they are more difficult to understand at first, they turn out to be much more useful!
Hope it helps